# How to use wordpress wpdb class to insert data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress I am try to create table and insert data to that table. so within the wordpress database I created table called 'album' then I created directory called 'my-codes'(within root directory/ same level with 'wp-admin' , 'wp-content, 'wp-includes' directories)

within that directory I created `insert.php` then i added following code

```
<?php       
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->album , array("ID"=>1, "Name"=>'something'), array("%d", "%s"));

 ?>
```

but it give this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\my-codes\insert.php` what is the mistake I did, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the Wordpress files within your script, so that you have access to Wordpress' `$wpdb` object:

```
require_once( '../wp-load.php' );
```

This will load *all of Wordpress*, even the functionality you don't need. If you want to only load the database part, [read this article](http://www.stormyfrog.com/using-wpdb-outside-wordpress/).

---

**Update** - The first argument to the `insert` method should be the name of your table:

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'album',
     array("ID"=>1, "Name"=>'something'),
     array("%d", "%s")
);
```

Comment: @user1784592 - The first argument to the `insert` method should be a string. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Sir, this question not related to above question, so if we want to retrieve data or update we have create separate files for each function isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
require (dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/wp-blog-header.php');
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/compat.php');
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php');
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/classes.php');

require_wp_db();
global $wpdb; // Look look! Over here! line 270 in wp-settings.php

if ( !empty($wpdb->error) )
        dead_db();

 //Execute your query here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [WordPress Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) instead of creating a custom table, unless **options** won't fit your needs. Also, place all your code in your theme's `functions.php`. That way, you won't need to load any other WordPress files externally. They're already loaded for you automatically if your code is in functions.php.

Here's a quick example of how to store data in the database using options ( taken from the WP Codex article linked above ):

```
// Create an option to the database
add_option( $option, $value = , $deprecated = , $autoload = 'yes' );

// Removes option by name.
delete_option( $option );

// Fetch a saved option
get_option( $option, $default = false );

// Update the value of an option that was already added.
update_option( $option, $newvalue );
```

Options are much easier to implement and generally less error prone than direct database access. :)